# How do I get around a transaction check error in an RPM that needs to overwrite a configuration file?

Tags: rpm, packaging, rpm-spec

I'm packing something and the upstream provider clobbers a configuration file.

```
Transaction check error:
  file /etc/acme-engine/acme-engine-fpm.conf from install of acme-1-74.1.el7.noarch conflicts with file from package ...
  file /etc/acme-server/config from install of acme-1-74.1.el7.noarch conflicts with file from package ...
```

I'm just packaging this stuff. You can see here that upstream is overwriting configuration files provided by another package. What is the right way to package this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to not package the same path as something in the base repositories, unless you are planning to replace the whole package and provide all its dependencies.

You should package alternative files that can be included or used to replace the files in the base OS. Otherwise, you’ll get the error above.